# How to ask Mathematica to display answer in "$\LaTeX$" form

Tags: output-formatting, display

I am not sure how to explain it, but whenever I compute something in *Mathematica*, the output always spits back the result in a *Mathematica* language as opposed to easy-to-read equations.

It's troublesome if my answer contains multiplies of parentheses and if my matrix is large.

Is there a way to make *Mathematica* display answers in "$\LaTeX$" form? So for instance, if i compute

```
RowReduce[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

How do I make it spit out a square matrix instead of giving me back `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`?

Comment: Try: `{{1,0},{0,1}}//MatrixForm`

Comment: There is also `TeXForm`. `TeXForm[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]` gives: $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site. Your question displays a bit more nicely now, too. ;) For future reference, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)'s the guide to formatting your posts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two possible answers.

1. [`TexForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html) converts a Mathematica expression into something you can use to paste it in TeX:

   ```
   TeXForm[x/Sqrt[5]]
   ==> \frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}
   ```

   A usually more convenient way of achieving this is right-clicking output, and selecting `Copy as | LaTeX`.
2. If all you're looking for is a neater display form *inside Mathematica*, then have a look at [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixForm.html) and [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraditionalForm.html).

   ```
   m = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
   TraditionalForm[m]
   MatrixForm[m]
   ```

   [image]

   Be careful only to use these commands to *display already existing values*. For example, when you're writing something like

   ```
   m = TraditionalForm[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}];
   Eigenvalues[m]
   ```

   then `m` is not assigned the matrix, but its `TraditionalForm` representation, which does not behave like a matrix anymore. The output of the above is simply a silly line:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am not solely interested in just displaying matrices, but also simplifying integrals, expressions, etc...

Comment: @jak Then use a more illustrative example... You can't make matrices the focus of your question and expect us to divine that you actually wanted to simplify integrals

Comment: Actually I just found the solution. Under "preference" and "evaluation" in Mathematica, we can switch the output cells to TraditionalForm

Comment: Good to see you posting again, David.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My activity on SE highly depends on what I'm currently using. Blame Haskell for my inactivity :-)